# Storing data from MySQL to PHP Array to return with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a MySQL table with cols `| btn_id | btn_title | btn_bg | btn_text |`.

I am trying to get the data in the table to a `php array` and then return via `JSON` so the array can be used in the JS document requesting the `PHP/MySQL Data`. Respective of row and columns/index.

So far i have:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
         FROM btn_color_presets
         ';

$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$array = array(); // 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) // 
{
     $array[] = $row;
     $index++;
}
```

**Q.** Now i wish to return a JSON Array made from the array of data. How do i proceed here?

Note: I am horrible with arrays and not entirely sure i have the correct method above for my requirements, but i think it is correct.

Comment: You don't need `$index`, just use `$array[] = $row` to add a new element to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `json_encode` after the loop:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Ah brilliant so i was along the right lines. Thanks Barmar!